# In a Single page app, how to call multiple disparate services without asking the user to relogin

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a single page web app which needs to talk to disparate services. To talk to each of these services, it requires a separate Oauth token. To acquire these tokens, I will be forced to ask the user to login separately for cross-domain calls. How to prevent this so that user logs in just once?

Edit 1: Added clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not need to have the user signin again for every token. Once the user signs in on first request, the token issuer will create a session cookie and use that establish user's identity in subsequent requests. If you are using Azure AD use msal.js library to simplify your coding. AFAIK, it uses a zero-size frame for all token requests after the first one.

Comment: The first token will validate API calls for domain1. But I will need a different token to send with calls for domain2....

Comment: Then to get the token for domain2 I will need the user to sign in again, right?

Comment: No, the user will be already signed in. AAD will have the user's authn cookie. You will need to ask a new access token. It should be issued to you silently, with no further user interaction. MSAL.JS or ADAL.JS toolkits should help you here.